# Are changes saved automatically in Canon's DPP 4?

Tags: canon, software, canon-dpp

After editing a photo in Canon's DPP 4, do you have to save the photo after the changes are made, or is it done automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You have to save them. The easiest way to apply changes to all edited images I found is to switch the working directory - DPP asks you to save changes to all edited files then.

It is very annoying, since the program tends to crash frequently, so it is easy to loose hours of work if you work on a large picture set and don't save the changes.

Comment: I'm in the habit of hitting [Ctrl+S] every time before I go from one image to the next.